# Is there a Sobolev map $\mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ whose differential zig-zags between a value and its negative?

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces, examples-counterexamples, weak-derivatives

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^4$ be open subset. Does there exist a **non-smooth** Sobolev map $f \in W^{1,p}(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^4)$ such that $df \in \{A,-A\}$ almost everywhere, where $A \in \text{GL}(\mathbb{R}^4)$ is fixed?

> I am trying to see if there is a non-trivial Sobolev map whose **invertible** differential is doing "zig-zag" between some value and its negative. Of course, if $df=A$ is constant a.e., then $f$ must be affine.

In one-dimension, we have such a phenomena:

Just take $f(x)=|x|$ on $(-1,1)$; then $f' \in \{1,-1 \}$. It seems to me that in higher dimensions, the constraint is harder to satisfy, though if we relax the invertibility condition, it's easy: Take

$$ f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=(|x_1|,|x_1|,|x_1|,|x_1|).$$

Then $df(x)=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
\text{sign}(x_1)&0&0&0\\\text{sign}(x_1)&0&0&0\\ \text{sign}(x_1)&0&0&0\\ \text{sign}(x_1)&0&0&0
\end{matrix}
\right)$.

Trying to make $df$ invertible, we can modify $f$ to

$$ f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=(|x_1|,|x_2|,|x_3|,|x_4|),$$

but now $$df(x)=\left(
\begin{matrix}
\text{sign}(x_1)&0&0&0\\0&\text{sign}(x_2)&0&0\\ 0&0&\text{sign}(x_3)&0\\ 0&0&0&\text{sign}(x_4)
\end{matrix}
\right)$$ switches between $2^4=16$ different values, since we can change each variable separately from negative to positive.

*Comment:* The reason I chose $4$ dimensions, is that I am interested in even dimensions greater than $2$, and this was the smallest one. I don't know the answer even for mappings $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$.

**Edit:**

In dimension $2$, we can try do the following:

Write $f(x,y)=(|x|,y \text{sign}(x))$. Then, *if* $f$ were Sobolev, then clearly we would have $df =\text{sign}(x) \cdot \text{Id}$. However, [I don't think the map $(x,y) \to y \text{sign}(x)$ is Sobolev](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2982991/is-the-function-fx-y-y-cdot-textsignx-sobolev).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No such a function does not exist. There is a theorem due to Ball and James that says that if you have a Sobolev function whose gradient takes the values $A$ and $B$, then necessarily $A-B$ is a rank one matrix. See Proposition 2.1 in [Mueller's lecture notes](https://www.mis.mpg.de/preprints/ln/lecturenote-0298.pdf). In your case $B=-A$ so $A-B=2A$ would have to be rank 1 which is not possible since you are assuming that the matrix is invertible.

Comment: Thanks! This result looks very interesting. It is stated for Lipschitz maps, not arbitrary Sobolev maps, but I guess that this does not matter? (If I understood correctly the proof, it is based on the symmetry of the second distributional derivatives, which should hold for any Sobolev map, not just  Lipschitz  ones, right?)

Comment: Yes, it does not matter. Since the gradient is bounded, you can prove that in each ball a Sobolev function is actually Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: Thanks again for referring me to this nice theorem. By the way, I think you might be interested in this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/300700/is-a-sobolev-map-with-smooth-minors-smooth